# Compare part of an input string using strcmp() in C

Tags: c, strcmp

Normally strcmp is used with two arguments [e.g. strcmp(str1,"garden")], and it will return 0 if both are the same.

Is it possible to compare part of the input, say the first five character of the input? (for example, `strcmp(str1,"garde",5)`)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(void) {

    char str1[] = "garden";

    if (strcmp(str1, "garden") == 0)
    {
        printf("1");
    }
    if (strcmp(str1, "garden", 6) == 0)
    {
        printf("2");
    }
    if (strcmp(str1, "garde", 5) == 0)
    {
        printf("3");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need strncmp http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncmp/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use strncmp:

```
if (strncmp(str, "test", 4) == 0) { printf("it matches!"); }
```

See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncmp/ for more info.

Comment: Hey Troy thanks for replying. Does it works with 3 arguments cuz I get this error, prog.c:10:29: error: macro "strcmp" passed 3 arguments, but takes just 2

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for [`strncmp()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncmp/).

Keep in mind that C does not supports overloading, so each "variation" of the same function has an unique name.

Comment: Hey Crozin, thanks. Which answer should I approve since both of you answer at about the same time lol...